# Description Labels When Using Beamer's structuresmallcapsserif

Tags: beamer, fonts, description

I have developed my own little beamer "template" with the font theme
`structuresmallcapsserif` and use this for a few years now.

I recently noted that the content of the slides appears in sans
serif as planned, but at description the label in serif.

I have experimented with `structuresmallcapsserif`'s options and found
no difference.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

MWE (you can leave `[17pt]` out, but I put this in for easier viewing):

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\framesubtitle{Subtitle}

    \begin{description}
        \item [09:00] Opening Remarks
        \item [17:00] Closing Remarks
    \end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{series=\normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{series=\normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{description item}{series=\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \begin{description}
        \item [09:00] Opening Remarks
        \item [17:00] Closing Remarks
    \end{description}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item [09:00] Opening Remarks
        \item [17:00] Closing Remarks
    \end{itemize}   

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Opening Remarks
        \item Closing Remarks
    \end{enumerate}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```